# On the fly tags generation for XML Builders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby

I have a hash like,

```
object = { :type => 'book', :name => 'RoR', :price => 33 }
```

OR

```
object = { :type => 'wig', :name => 'Elvis-Style', :price => 40, :color => 'black' }
```

The problem is that keys in above hash may be different all the time or even increase and decrease depending upon the object type.

What I want to do generate XML for above hashes using `Xml::Builder`. The XML tags are decided by the `keys` in the hash and `text` inside a tag is value corresponding that key.

I can use `eval` to do this like below. However, I think there must be a better way to do it.

```
object.each do |key, text|
  eval("xml.#{key.to_s} do
          #{text}
        end
      ")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails supports `to_xml` on Hash classes.

```
hash = { :type => 'book', :name => 'RoR', :price => 33 }
hash.to_xml
# Returns
# <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
# <hash>
#   <type>book</type>
#   <name>RoR</name>
#   <price type=\"integer\">33</price>
# </hash>
```

If you want to skip the types then:

```
hash.to_xml(:skip_types => true)
```

If you want to give a different root then:

```
hash.to_xml(:root => 'options')
```

Comment: Can this method be adapted to emit the tags from an xml object, rather than output a complete xml file?

Answer (score 2):

```
@object.each do |k, v|
  xml.tag!(k.to_s, v)
end
```

Comment: That was great. However it did not work properly. This one did work though. http://pastie.org/851304

Answer (score 1):

This one worked.

```
@object.each do |k, v|
  xml.tag!(k.to_s, v)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   out << "<#{key}>#{html_escape(value)}</#{key}>"
```